# Applying Autofilter on specific column using distinct values in vbscript

Tags: excel, vbscript, autofilter

There are some excels in a folder.Every excel follows same template.There is a 'K' column in every sheet.This column consists some codes( these codes can be distinct or duplicates).I am trying to apply autofilter on these values and want to save every distinct code in a separate excel file.(Like if an excel file is having codes 15478,15478 and 17832, then there will be one excel file having both codes 15478 and there will be second excel file having 17832.)And this i have to do for every excel file present in the folder.

```
strPath="C:\Testr"
Set objExcel= CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible= True

Const xlUp= -4162

'To store every excel sheet column values in array
Dim a(), val

Set objFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFso.GetFolder (strPath)

'To pick out the only distinct values from array
 Set objDict= CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
 objDict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare

'Searching for xls files
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
If objFso.GetExtensionName(objFile.Path) = "xls" Then
    objExcel.Workbooks.Open(objFile.Path)


    'Counting all the used rows
    With objExcel.Activeworkbook.Sheets("PAAF")
    rowcount=.Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row-2

    msgbox rowcount
    End With

    'dynamic array
    Redim Preserve a(rowcount)

    'Collecting distinct values in dictionary object
    for i=7 to rowcount
        a(i-7) = objExcel.Activeworkbook.Sheets("PAAF").Cells(i,11).Value
    objDict(a(i-7)) = a(i-7)

    Next


    n = objDict.Items

    REM The problem is here, though i am able to get unique values,
     REM but these values are getting processed for every excel because 
     REM the loop is starting for 0 .Ex- if one sheet is having code 19873,
     REM it will get processed for second sheet also whether it is present that 
     REM or not.

    For i=0 to ubound(n)
    msgbox n(i)




With objExcel.Activeworkbook.Sheets("PAAF")

    'Passing dictionary stored values to apply autofilter on    
    .Range("K6").AutoFilter 11,"="& n(i)

End With

fn=objFso.GetFileName(objFile.Path)
objExcel.Activeworkbook.saveAs("C:\Test2\"&"Output"& fn &i &".xls")

Next
```

Is there any other way to get distinct values from array to apply filter on these values?I tried my best to explain my problem but let me know if anything is not clear....!
[Template of Excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfzIW.jpg)

Comment: Is there a problem with your existing code? If yes, what is it?

Comment: Actually there is no problem in code but it is not working as i want it to work.My code needs some modification.Lets say i have only one code in one excel and that is 10757, the above written code will apply filter on it and save this excel in other location.Now it will open 2nd excel which is in folder, let's say this sheet has 19034,19034 & 18324 code, so two excel will be generated one is having 19034 and other is having 18324 but except this the previous excel 17057 is also getting generated.

Comment: Now if it goes for 3rd excel then except 3rd excel sheet code previous two excel sheets will also get generated.I know it is because that is because dictionary items loop but if i remove it i won't b able to pass unique values to array.And for every value present in excel whether duplicate or distinct, the excel will get generated.Like if there is 16850 code in an excel 11 times, then 11 excel will get generated.

Comment: Why don't you clear the dictionary after opening each file? That way, it will only contain values from that specific file.  What's the purpose of the array `a()` ?

Comment: a() stores all code values present in a particular column,duplicate or distinct.I am using dictionary object to filter the duplicate values and only pass the distinct values to autofilter.I am a bit new in this stuff, so can you please tell me how to how to clear dictionary after opening each file?

Comment: i tried to clear dictionary by using objDict.RemoveAll(), and it is working fine now...Thanks a lot @TimWilliams for your help !!